# Set cursor position after search icon in SearchView Hint inside android toolbar

Tags: android, searchview, androidx

[image]

How can i set my cursor position after search icon in android toolbar hint.. its a androidx search view.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_icon"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
    MenuItem miSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.ic_action_search);
    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) miSearch.getActionView();

    mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSearchView.setFocusable(true);
            mSearchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
            mSearchView.setIconified(false);
        }
    });
```